Start CSS transformation at mouse position
I simply want the transformation to start at the clicked mouse position.
It does not work (as I expected). Why not and what should I change?


var x, y;
const hint = document.getElementById('hint');
const pageOverlay = document.getElementById('pageOverlay');

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

  document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    console.info('clicked at ' + x + ', ' + y);
    hide(hint);
    expand(pageOverlay);
  });

  document.onmousemove = function (e) {
    x = e.clientX;
    y = e.clientY;
  };
});

function hide(elm) {
  elm.setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden; opacity: 0");
}

function expand(elm) {
  elm.setAttribute("style", 
   "transform-origin:" + x + "px " + y + "px;" +
   "visibility: visible;" +
   "opacity: 1;" +
   "transform: scale(1)");
}
.pageOverlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue; 
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;  
  transition: 0.8s linear;
  transform: scale(.2);
}
<span id="hint">Click somewhere!<br/><br/>
 I want/expect the transformation to start at the mouse position.</span>
 
 <div id="pageOverlay" class="pageOverlay">
  <h1>Overlay</h1> 
 </div>



Codepen: https://codepen.io/r-w-c/pen/jOoPRBY

How do you expect it to work?

@Steffen: As I wrote. Where you click, I want the overlay div to expand (scale from 0.2 to 1) from there.

Do I understand correctly that overlay should grow from a place where user clicked or how does your intended result look like?

With how you positioned the element, I don't think this can work by just changing the transform-origin. If I understood correctly, how exactly you want this to behave (not absolutely sure either), then I think you will have to position the element at the click coordinates first (centered around that x/y, probably), and then figure out where to set the origin so that when it expands from that starting position, at its final size of 100vh/100vh, it will look as if it had been positioned at 0/0 in the first place.

@CBroe, that could make sense. I am going to try that, see if it works. Thanks.

@CBroe,unfortunately it did not work.
elm.setAttribute("style",
"left: " + x + ";" +
"top: " + y + ";" +
"width: 100vw;" +
"height: 100vh;" +
"transform-origin:" + x + "px " + y + "px;" +
"visibility: visible;" +
"opacity: 1;" +
"transform: scale(1)");
}
Still start the transformation at another position (0,0 I guess).

@NoOorZ: Exactly.

OK, so I don't understand exactly what you want, but I think I got an idea of it. The issue persists because you're not only animating the scale effect, but also the re-positioning of the element. By changing your transition property to transition: transform 0.8s linear;, the overlay will move instantly and then start expanding.


var x, y;
const hint = document.getElementById('hint');
const pageOverlay = document.getElementById('pageOverlay');

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

  document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    console.info('clicked at ' + x + ', ' + y);
    hide(hint);
    expand(pageOverlay);
  });

  document.onmousemove = function (e) {
    x = e.clientX;
    y = e.clientY;
  };
});

function hide(elm) {
  elm.setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden; opacity: 0");
}

function expand(elm) {
  elm.setAttribute("style", 
   "transform-origin:" + x + "px " + y + "px;" +
   "visibility: visible;" +
   "opacity: 1;" +
   "transform: scale(1)");
}
.pageOverlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue; 
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;  
  transition: transform 0.8s linear;
  transform: scale(.2);
}
<span id="hint">Click somewhere!<br/><br/>
 I want/expect the transformation to start at the mouse position.</span>
 
 <div id="pageOverlay" class="pageOverlay">
  <h1>Overlay</h1> 
 </div>




I believe @RWC maybe also isn't looking at "transform-origin:" + x + "px " + y + "px;" correctly. This is origin coordinate relative to the object that is being transformed as is nicely explained and depicted here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin So if you click on a whole webpage at 1,1 the animation will start at 1,1 inside the element being animated, not at the 1,1 of the page. To be consistent with the transformation effect, you would need to use x,y of click to move the element to that x,y then star the transform-origin at fixed location (eg "center").

@LuxZg I thought that too, but the element is 100vw and 100vh, so transform-origin moves it around the screen, although not perfectly. If you remove the transform: scale(1) from the expand function, you can see that it moves around.

Thanks @Steffen
Steffen, your code snippet does exactly what I wanted and your explanation is spot on. I thought transform-origin worked differently. Haven't done much with animations and transformations.

Here a demo: https://codepen.io/r-w-c/pen/QWRbrzB
The page will contain more images and if you click on an image, it is like you are expanding that image. I also would like to have a cross fade effect, but still have to find out how to do that. Definitely no CSS expert.
